# How do I kill a Bash script if it can't find or read a file?

Tags: bash

I have written a small bash program which needs to read a file with name `input`. I want the script to print the message `file not found` and exit or kill itself if it can't find the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just before reading, check if the file exists:

```
if [ ! -f input ]; then
  echo "File Not found"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: add a #!/bin/bash shebang at the top of the file, or this will kill the current terminal.

Comment: Your code is not working in my computer showing the error message      [: missing `]'

Comment: There must be a space between `input` and `]`. Common typo =)

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho Thanks :) Came back after a break, hence delay :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the Bash Exit Handler

You can use Bash's `set -e` option to handle most similar situations automatically, with system-generated (but generally sensible) error messages. For example:

```
$ set -e; ls /tmp/doesnt_exist
ls: cannot access /tmp/doesnt_exist: No such file or directory
```

Note that the -e option will also cause the current shell to exit immediately with a non-zero exit status after displaying the error message. This is a quick-and-dirty way to get what you want.

#### Manually Test for a Readable File

If you really need a custom message, then you want to use a test conditional. For example, to ensure that a file exists *and is readable* you could use something similar to the following:

```
if [[ -r "/path/to/input" ]]; then
    : # do something with "input"
else
   # Send message to standard error.
   echo "file not found" > /dev/stderr

   # Exit with EX_DATAERR from sysexits.h.
   exit 65
fi
```

#### See Also

See `man 1 test` for a more complete list of possible test conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for valuable info Bro... @CodeGnome